# Absolute value minimization with non-convex constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, non-convex-optimization

I want to solve the following optimization problem in $x\in\mathbb{R}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & |ax+b|+|cx+d|\\ \text{subject to} & x \in [x_1,x_2] \cup [x_3,x_4]\end{array}$$

where $[x_1,x_2] \cap [x_3,x_4]=\emptyset$. Is there a way to transform it to a LP form?

Comment: You could convert it to MILP, but it will be easier to solve it separately on each interval and the the better result.

Comment: If the feasible region were $[x_1, x_2]$, would you be able to write it as an LP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the feasible region is nonconvex, you cannot model it as a single linear program.  Here's a MILP formulation:
\begin{align}
\text{minimize} &&y_1+y_2\\
\text{subject to} 
&&y_1 &\ge ax+b \\
&&y_1 &\ge -(ax+b) \\
&&y_2 &\ge cx+d \\
&&y_2 &\ge -(cx+d) \\
&&x_1 (1-z) + x_3 z &\le x \le x_2 (1-z) + x_4 z\\
&&z &\in \{0,1\}
\end{align}

Comment: This argument is too simple. Sometimes you can apply a transformation of variables to turn a nonconvex set into a convex one. Not saying that that is the case here, but I do not see the value of your answer compared to the comments already posted.